# avoid expansion of dependencies for unused makefile targets

Tags: makefile

Is there a way to avoid expansion of target dependencies for targets that are not used.  If the below makefile is invoked to build the fasttarget, the shell slowcommand is still being invoked.  Other options that would prevent the fasttarget from running the slowcommand would also be appreciated though I would prefer to avoid a recursive make.

```
slow = $(shell slowcommand)

.PHONY: fasttarget slowtarget

fasttarget :
    fastcommand    

slowtarget : $(slow)

%.slowitem.output : %.slowitem.input
    buildslowitem $< $@
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cite from the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html):

> **Rule Definition**
>
> A rule is always expanded the same way, regardless of the form:
>
> ```
> immediate : immediate ; deferred
>     deferred
> ```

`immediate` in this context means "during the first phase of a makefile examination", that is, in the phase where the dependency tree for later execution of rules is constructed. Obviously `make` at this point in time needs to settle all the variable contents of the dependency relation `target : prerequisites` to concrete values, i.e. from variable references and function calls to file names which really exist (at this moment) in the file system. No amount of trickery can drive `make` away from this task as it is not equipped to evaluate the dependency graph dynamically "on the go". This has the benefit that `make` can beautifully parallelize its rules but the downside is that the complete dependency graph must be known in advance, even the parts which will not be used. The only way out for your construction is to use two different makefiles (or the same but with different visibility via `if` et al) and to present the `slow` target and its prerequisites to the `make` evaluator only in a subsequent invocation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify that you're using GNU make but since you're using GNU make syntax I will reply in kind.

You can try using [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

slowtarget: $$(slow)
```

This should prevent the `$(slow)` variable from being expanded until/unless the `slowtarget` target actually needs to be built.

Comment: Yes, I am using GNU make.  Adding the extra $ before (slow) prevented the expansion until I added the .SECONDEXPANSION:.  After I added .SECONDEXPANSION:, things were back where I started and slow is still expanded when running the fasttarget.

Comment: Without .SECONDEXPANSION it won't work to run slowtarget; you're basically just saying that slowtarget depends on the literal string `$(slow)` which obviously does not exist.  If this doesn't work there's probably no way to avoid it without recursive make.